# Custom Row Animations for UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, xcode, animation, uitableview, reloaddata

When I need to refresh UITableView I need some custom animations. I look for something like :

```
[self.table reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
```

but to set my own animations. It would be perfect if this animation would be on UITableViewCell bases, because I need to animate onelly some of the elements in cell.

**What I try to do:**

I have custom cell like this

```
 ___________________________________
|  lable   |separator|  lable 2     |
 -----------------------------------
```

I would like lable 2 to swipe left or right, but not the whole cell.

Marko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in .h you will have  reloadInWithMyOwnAnimation  BOOL variable. Before you reload the section set it as YES. after reloading you set it as NO.

```
    reloadingWithMyOwnAnimation = YES;

    [tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];

    reloadingWithMyOwnAnimation = NO;



    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        UITableViewCell *myCustomCell = cell;

        BOOL swipeLeft = YES;


        if (reloadingWithMyOwnAnimation == YES) {


            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.8f animations:^{

                if (swipeLeft) {
                    //Swipe Right

                    //Get the label frame
                    CGRect myLabelFrame = myCustomCell.textLabel.frame;


                    //Set it to 0
                    myLabelFrame.origin.x = 0;

                    //Move it to Right
                    myLabelFrame.origin.x += cell.bounds.size.width;


                    //Set the frame of the label
                    [myCustomCell.textLabel setFrame:myLabelFrame];


                }
                else{
                    //Swipe Left

                    //Get the label frame
                    CGRect myLabelFrame = myCustomCell.textLabel.frame;


                    //Set it to 0
                    myLabelFrame.origin.x = 0;

                    //Move it to Left
                    myLabelFrame.origin.x -= cell.bounds.size.width;


                    //Set the frame of the label
                    [myCustomCell.textLabel setFrame:myLabelFrame];



                }

                [myCustomCell layoutSubviews];


            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                NSLog(@"Done");


            }];


        }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to have custom UITableViewCell class and there you have to implement a method something like,

```
- (void)swipeLabel2Out {

    UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{

        // set the frame of your label2

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        // hide your label2
    }
}
```

you can easily keep track of your cell using the method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and call the [cell swipeLabel2Out]; method.

Answer (score 0):

**Hope this will help you**

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
             cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        NSString *MyIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"MyIdentifier%d",indexPath.row];

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                           reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 0, 100, 50)];
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        label.text = @"Test";
        label.tag = indexPath.row;
        [label setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:label];
        [arrayLabel addObject:label];


        UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipedGesture:)];
        swipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
        swipe.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
        [label addGestureRecognizer:swipe];

        }

        return cell;
    }

    - (void)swipedGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
    {

        [UIView animateWithDuration:1
                         animations:^{
                             CGRect rect = label.frame;
                             rect.origin.x = 320;
                             label.frame = rect;
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             NSLog(@"completion block");
                         }];

    }
```